# custom role provider not working on IIS but work fine in VS development server

Tags: asp.net, iis, roleprovider

After deep googling I'm not found any solution or ways to troubleshoot my problem, so ask here.
In first part of web.config

```
......
   <location path="DevReg.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="C,csvImportExport"/>
        <deny users="*,?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
.......
  <system.web>
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MyRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="MyRoleProvider" type="DataAccess.Common.MyRoleProvider, DataAccess" applicationName="myapp" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
.......
```

Main WebApp in other project in the same solution. 
When I run app in Visual Studio provider run fine -- authorization work as must, I also can call my provider from code (e.g IsUserInRole return right result). But after deployment to local IIS (Win 7/ IIS 7.5). I tried with VirtualDirectory and with WebApp with no luck.

When my app run in IIS look like server never use Role provider, only call Initialize method on start and newer more.

Please give me right direction to troubleshoot this problem, if need I will show more details.

Comment: What is your application pool settings?

Comment: are you using a different database when on IIS vs local host?

Comment: @KrishanuDey application pool is default, I make only one change its allow 32 bit app to run because my host 64 bit

Comment: @peroija is the same base on same host, and connection string never change

Comment: @sage444 how did you solve this issue? i have no clue why IIS is ignoring my custom Role Provider

Comment: @Djavier89 this is very old question, and I can't remember details so please check my answer below is all that I can give you as help

Answer (score 0):

create a new `Application Pool` with `Managed Pipeline Mode` set to `Integrated`. Set the `Identity` value to `NetworkService`. After this set the newly created `Application Pool` as `Application Pool` of the site.

Comment: Thanks you for reply, this changed nothing but can you provide some explanation about your suggestion, this may get me some point to research

Answer (score 0):

After changing point of view I found the problem. In project we also using one ugly HttpHandler with a row: `Context.SkipAuthorization = true;` that make all my troubles.